# Java - Name of Array Equals Value of String Variable

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables, arraylist

I have 10 array lists and a String variable.
I have one function/method that allows the user to select one of the array lists to add to. Currently, that function changes the value of a string "chosen" to the value of the proper array list name.

Another function is started in which adding elements to the arraylist happens. However, I am struggling to come up with a solution on how to change which arraylist is being added to based upon what was selected by the user.

This code doesn't work but say it was:

```
chosen.add(whatUserEntered);
```

Normally you can put in the arrayList name and add .add(whateverTheUserIsEntering) and itll work fine.

So how can I have the name of an arrayList equal that of a String variable's value?

Comment: Use a `Map`.  An old name for a Map is "symbol table," used to bind names in your program to memory addresses.  That's basically what you're doing here.

Comment: Simple.. Keep a map of <whatUserEntered, actualArrayListReference> . So, when user selects an arraylist name, you can internally get out **your** reference that represents it and add the values :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a `Map` to bind string names to lists.  When you need to put things together at run time (as opposed to compile time, as you show with your example `choosen.add(userEntered)`), you usually need to use a Map.

This works with strings read from a file (say to bind XML names to objects) or things like interpreters where you have to keep track of user variables by name.

```
public class SymbolTableExample
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Some array lists
      ArrayList<String> cats = new ArrayList<>();
      ArrayList<String> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
      ArrayList<String> beetles = new ArrayList<>();
      ArrayList<String> cows = new ArrayList<>();

      // Bind names to them
      Map<String,List<String>> binding = new HashMap<>();
      binding.put( "cats", cats );
      binding.put( "dogs", dogs );
      binding.put( "beetles", beetles );
      binding.put( "cows", cows );

      // Pretend the user enters some input here
      String userChoice = "cats";
      String userEntered = "flufy";
      binding.get( userChoice ).add( userEntered );

   }
}
```

Comment: What are the advantages to using `Map<String, List<String>>` instead of `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`?

Comment: @Arc676 I guess ["Program to an interface."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) Since I didn't need any special methods from `ArrayList` here, I just selected `List` without really thinking about it.  I suppose there could be good reasons to use `ArrayList` too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

```
public interface Map<K,V>
```

You can use the method

```
V put(K key, V value)
```

to assign a value to a key, so you can set `ArrayList`s for different keys or add new ones..

Since you are using `ArrayList`s, you could make your make your Map like so:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>)> myArrays
```

Then, to add a value to an array with a given key, use

```
myArrays.get(userChosenArrayKey).add(whatUserEntered)
```